# Do I need to adjust for length while comparing cosine similarity across different pairs of documents?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cosine-similarity

Assume that I have two documents, A and B, and each document has two versions, 1 and 2. I calculate the cosine similarities for (A1, A2) and (B1, B2). Let Sa = cosine(A1, A2), and Sb = cosine(B1, B2).

If Sa < Sb, can I say that there has been a greater change or update for Document A than Document B?

A paper states that: "The longer a pair of documents, the more probable a word is included in both documents, leading to a lower likelihood that the documents will differ (see appendix B for an analytical proof)." The paper can be found [HERE](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1475-679X.2010.00396.x).

Is this true? This statement is likely true for the Jaccard similarity since the size of the vocabulary is limited. However, the cosine similarity is an angle, and intuitively the length of the documents shouldn't matter. If this is true,  what is the best way to adjust the similarity scores for length so that I can make a comparison across different pairs of documents. Thank you!

I run some stats based on 22861 pairs. Indeed, the doc length and the similarity are highly positively correlated. 
Averages:

```
WC2          4829.637374
WCl          4389.449193
WCA          4609.543283
Cosine         0.750225
CosineR        0.786806
Jaccard        0.606962
JaccardR       0.653031
```

Where:

WC2 is the clean word count of version2, excluding stopwords, numbers, and punctuations. 
WCA is the average(WC1, and WC2). 
Cosine is the clean cosine similarity based on the clean words.
CosineR is the cosine similarity based on all tokens(including stopwords, numbers, and punctuations).

Here is the Pearson correlation matrix:

```
                WC2       WCl       WCA    Cosine   CosineR   Jaccard  JaccardR
WC2       1.000000  0.886743  0.972220  0.121300  0.122131  0.107936  0.123040
WCl       0.886743  1.000000  0.970310  0.238503  0.257914  0.220078  0.254090
WCA       0.972220  0.970310  1.000000  0.184233  0.194497  0.167911  0.193036
Cosine    0.121300  0.238503  0.184233  1.000000  0.978050  0.982066  0.971082
CosineR   0.122131  0.257914  0.194497  0.978050  1.000000  0.948325  0.981853
Jaccard   0.107936  0.220078  0.167911  0.982066  0.948325  1.000000  0.975908
JaccardR  0.123040  0.254090  0.193036  0.971082  0.981853  0.975908  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the length of the document is not reflected in cosine similarity. You can multiply the cosine similarity to the absolute value of the difference of the length of the documents (`||A1|-|A2||*Sa` and `||B1|-|B2||*Sb`).